# Best way to parse an invalid HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing

Is there a better approach to parse an invalid HTML then applying Tidy on it?

Side Note : 
There are some situation when you can't have Tidy available.
Regexp is also not recommended I understood for parsing html.

Comment: In situations where you don't have Tidy available, you should install it. Or you could just not use broken HTML in the first place.

Comment: Are you serious ? There are at least a couple of times I was unable to do this best practice : invalid html code from clients that need it to be parsed, shared hosting with no option to install Tidy..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would try something like this: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

From that page:

> The function parses the HTML contained in the string source. Unlike loading XML, **HTML does not have to be well-formed to load**. This function may also be called statically to load and create a DOMDocument object.

Comment: it seems loadHTML objects to the same value for ID on two or more elements (although, this is probably coming up from libxml)

Answer (score 1):

[SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is known to be more lenient than PHP's native DOM functions.

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: @Gordon this time you were too quick :) He is looking to parse broken HTML.

Comment: which all DOM based parsers should be able to handle fine when using [libxml's HTML parser module](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html).