# PHP How do I remove script tags from URL?

Tags: php, url, tags, file-get-contents

I have url ( with file_get_contents ) and this link have script tags, how can I remove them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606792/best-way-to-parse-an-invalid-html-in-php

Also, your question has nothing to do with the URL.  You want to remove script tags from the resulting resource, correct?

Comment: What is this for? Are you trying to steal somebody else's content?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex (taken from the jQuery sourcecode).

```
$data = preg_replace('/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi', '', $data);
```

And before somebody is going to tell me that Regexes+HTML are an evil combination: You are right, but in this specific case it's perfecly valid since script tags have some specific behaviour such as that the first `</script>` will close the script tag; no matter if it's inside quotes etc.

However, if you plan to do anything else with the HTML data, use a HTML parser!

Comment: Thanks alot! It's work, more 7 minutes I'll make your comment the answer, the system says that I should to wait at least 7 minutes before I make answer. I grateful ^^

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [Writing secure PHP](http://www.addedbytes.com/writing-secure-php/)

Also, please don't steal content, if that's what you are doing.