# php Xpath getting innerHTML with innerHTML tags

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have a HTML file formatted like this:

```
<p class="p1">subject</p>
<p class="p2">detail <span>important</span></p>

<p class="p1">subject</p>
<p class="p2">detail<span>important</span></p>
```

I wrote a PHP code to automatically get each p1 and it's detail to insert them into my mysql table.

this is my code:

```php
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTMLFile("file.html");

$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);

$subject = $xpath->query('//p');


for ($i = 0 ; $i < $subject->length-1 ; $i ++) {

if ($subject->item($i)->getAttribute("class") == "p1")
    echo $subject->item($i)->nodeValue;
}
...
```

This is not my full code, but the problem is:

```
echo $subject->item($i)->nodeValue;
```

Which gives me `<p>detail important</p>`, without the `<span></span>` tag.

It is so important to have the span tags around the "important" part of the detail. is there any function which can do that without getting headache?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [innerHTML in xPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615389/innerhtml-in-xpath)

Comment: I found this SO entry that I hope will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286362/php-dom-get-nodevalue-html-without-stripping-tags

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question :) Thanks to SimpleHTMLDOM

```
foreach($html->find('p') as $element) {

 switch ($element->class) {
      case 'p1':
                     $subject = $element;
                     break;
      case 'p2': $detail .= html_entity_decode($element);

 }
```

}

the trick is in:

```
html_entity_decode($element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to parse HTML, I run it through SimpleHTMLDOM:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I recommend using version 1.11.  For various reasons, 1.5 is rather broken.

Comment: SimpleHTMLDOM is defective by design, I would not recommend it therefore but instead something that's based on DomDocument, see as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606792/best-way-to-parse-an-invalid-html-in-php

Comment: The same problem here. it has only $element->plaintext. so if there is any tag in the element, it will be extracted as plain text :(

Answer (score 0):

Old query, but there is an one-liner. The OP should use:

`$subject = $xpath->query('//p/*');`

and then:

`echo $doc->saveHtml($subject->item($i));`

With the `*` you'll get the inner html (without the wrapping paragraph tag); without * you'll get the html with the wrapping paragraph;

Full example:

```
$html = '<div><p>ciao questa è una <b>prova</b>.</p></div>';
$dom = new DomDocument($html);
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $xpath->query('.//div/*'); // with * you get inner html without surrounding div tag; without * you get inner html with surrounding div tag
$innerHtml = $dom->saveHtml($node);
var_dump($innerHtml);
```

Output: `<p>ciao questa è una <b>prova</b>.</p>`